# Comparison between a DATE and a VARCHAR: How does it work?

Tags: sql, exasol

I have the following condition:

```sql
WHERE ORDER_DATE >= TO_DATE (CURRENT_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

The left part (`ORDER_DATE`) is stored as a `VARCHAR` and the right part is a `DATE`.
When I run the code I have no error; meaning that the comparison between a `VARCHAR` and a `DATE` is working.
I feel like the `VARCHAR` is converted in a `DATE` and then the comparison operator is applied; when I have `'0000-00-00'` data in the `ORDER_DATE` it returns a format error (`data exception - invalid value for YYYY format token; Value: '0000-00-00'`).
Can someone confirm that my hypothesis is right?

*Yes I know I should store or convert my `VARCHAR` in a `DATE` and then perform my comparison between two `DATE` and this is what I have done. However, I noticed this particularity and I would like to understand the reason behind!

Comment: I don't know how the varchar date is generated but that should be consistent. May be you need to datafix those different strings. Did you try CAST(ORDER_DATE AS DATE)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple strange things going on.  In terms of conversion:

```
WHERE ORDER_DATE >= TO_DATE(CURRENT_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
----------------------------^ CURRENT_DATE is converted to a string because TO_DATE() expects a string as the first argument
--------------------^ TO_DATE then converts the string to a date using the specified format
-----------------^ The comparison converts the ORDER_DATE to a date (and you might get a type conversion error).
```

Note:  This is based on the rules of Standard SQL.  I assume that Exasol follows these rules (which are consistent across databases).

Presumably, your `ORDER_DATE` is in the format YYYY-MM-DD.  If so, it is comparison safe and you can use:

```
ORDER_DATE >= TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Comment: Yes my `ORDER_DATE` is in format YYYY-MM-DD so the comparison of two `VARCHAR` is safe. However, in this case, is it a better practice to convert the `ORDER_DATE` in a `DATE` and apply the comparison on two `DATE` instead?  Example: ```WHERE CAST(ORDER_DATE AS DATE >= CURRENT_DATE```

Comment: @savag . . . No.  The correct practice is to stored `ORDER_DATE` as a string.  Period.  If you are stuck with `ORDER_DATE` as a string in YYYY-MM-DD format, then string comparisons will usually be faster than converting to a date.